# OR / AND operator in grepl o str_detect

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, grepl

If I execute the following code:

```
dplyr::filter(mtcars, grepl('RX4|Wag', type))
```

I get the result:

```
  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb          type
1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     Mazda RX4
2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 Mazda RX4 Wag
```

However, I need the following result:

```
  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb          type
   21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     Mazda RX4
```

How can I apply a **operator AND NOT** in str_detect or grepl to remove explicitly **'Wag'**?

Comment: If you don't want `Wag`, then what's the logic for having a pattern `RX4|Wag`? Did you mean "RX4 and not Wag"?

Comment: Exactly. In the first case an OR operator is applied, but I need AND NOT to remove 'Mazda RX4 Wag'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `^(?!.*Wag).*RX4` for that, where `(?!.*Wag)` is a negative lookahead throughout all the string. For instance,

```
grep('^(?!.*Wag).*RX4', c("Wag RX4 bag", "bag RX4 Wag", "bag RX4 bag"), perl = TRUE)
# [1] 3
```

So, in your case that would be

```
dplyr::filter(mtcars, grepl('^(?!.*Wag).*RX4', type, perl = TRUE))
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb      type
# 1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4 Mazda RX4
```

I'd agree that this pattern isn't really obvious, so you may want to do it in two steps, allowing to use usual AND and NOT:

```
dplyr::filter(mtcars, grepl('RX4', type) & !grepl('Wag', type))
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb      type
# 1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4 Mazda RX4
```

Comment: when I apply this code, I get the following result: **Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: invalid regular expression '^(?!.*Wag).*RX4', reason 'Invalid regexp'.** I'm probably doing something wrong; I'm not an expert in string treatment.

Comment: @majesus, ah no, sorry, I forgot to add `perl = TRUE` to the second line. Fixed.